# Using \cite with biber inside tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, biblatex, citing, biber

I'm using biber and want to cite references inside a tikzpicture. I followed this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68101/84886) that described how to do it with bibtex and it works nicely, but when switching to use biber, it doesn't work anymore:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[show/.style={circle,draw}]
\node[show]    (newpaper)    at    (0,2)    
    [label=right:{This 2011 paper ...}]    
    {\cite{newpaper}};
\node[show]    (oldpaper)   at     (0,0)    
     [label=right:{This paper came out in 1900 ...}]    
    {\cite{oldpaper}};
\draw[->]    (oldpaper) -- (newpaper);
\end{tikzpicture}


%\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{newerpaper}B. Becker, \emph{Even Newer Stuff}, 2012.
\bibitem{newpaper}C. Charles, \emph{New Stuff}, 2011.
\bibitem{oldpaper}H. Huckley, \emph{Old Stuff}, 1900.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

Does anyone know of a solution without me having to switch to use bibtex?

***UPDATE:***

As noted by several below, my original code I posted was an easy fix. The actual bug I found was a result of my larger LaTeX code and I found the issue. Here's the updated code that has the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=fig/]

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{newerpaper,
    author={B. Becker},
    title={Even Newer Stuff},
    date={2012}
}

@book{newpaper,
    author={C. Charles},
    title={New Stuff},
    date={2011}
}

@book{oldpaper,
    author={H. Huckley},
    title={Old Stuff},
    date={1900}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

%\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{tikzpicture}[show/.style={circle,draw}]
\node[show]    (newpaper)    at    (0,2)    
[label=right:{This 2011 paper ...}]    
{\cite{newpaper}};
\node[show]    (oldpaper)   at     (0,0)    
[label=right:{This paper came out in 1900 ...}]    
{\cite{oldpaper}};
\draw[->]    (oldpaper) -- (newpaper);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\tikzexternalenable

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The problem is with the `\tikzexternalize[prefix=fig/]` command. I got around this issue by adding `\tikzexternaldisable` before the tikzpicture and `\tikzexternalenable` after the tikzpicture.

Comment: At first glance, it seems to me it may well be working and the problem has nothing to do with the tikz drawings, but with the fact that you are supplying bibtex entries. Did you try to put these references in a .bib file and inputing it with `addbibresource`?

Comment: You say you're using `biblatex` but your bibliography is done by hand?  If' you're really doing things by hand, then don't use `biblatex`. If you're really using `biblatex` delete your hand-done bibliography and replace it with `\printbibliography` , tell `biblatex` where to find your `.bib` file (using `\addbibresource`) and let `biblatex` do the work.  See [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/2693).

Comment: The answer you link to is a bit misleading, since it uses a manually created bibliography just for the example. Nobody would likely ever do exactly that in practice.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I actually was using a separate bib file, but to illustrate the problem I took that example from the link I gave. It turns out my problem has to do with tikzexternalize. I updated my post to note this and I included one possible solution... I'm not sure if it's the correct one.

Comment: Well, you updated your question in a direction which seems different from the original one. Anyway, in your update, what's the point of loading `\usetikzlibrary{external}` if you are "getting around it" with `\tikzexternaldisable` in the only tikz drawing you have?

Comment: @gusbrs would it have been better if I started a whole new question? Again, please note that the code I posted is just for illustration purposes. I have some other tikz pictures that don't have citations within them.

Comment: Well, ok. Understood. Then, if you don't need to externalize this one, I guess you are done.

Comment: Still, I believe you could profit from this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301458/105447.

Comment: @gusbrs can you elaborate on how one can profit from this answer? I ran into the same problem and came here looking for a solution, but can't really see how to profit…

Comment: @FabianA. I believe I assumed the OP was having trouble with externalization (also) for the lack of `-shell-escape`. But it's long ago, so I'm not really sure what my reasoning was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you should move to `biblatex`'s way of dealing with the bibliography, rather than doing it by hand.
E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{newerpaper,
    author={B. Becker},
    title={Even Newer Stuff},
    date={2012}
}

@book{newpaper,
    author={C. Charles},
    title={New Stuff},
    date={2011}
}

@book{oldpaper,
    author={H. Huckley},
    title={Old Stuff},
    date={1900}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[show/.style={circle,draw}]
\node[show]    (newpaper)    at    (0,2)    
    [label=right:{This 2011 paper ...}]    
    {\cite{newpaper}};
\node[show]    (oldpaper)   at     (0,0)    
     [label=right:{This paper came out in 1900 ...}]    
    {\cite{oldpaper}};
\draw[->]    (oldpaper) -- (newpaper);
\end{tikzpicture}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

**Edit:** As it turned out, the issue is essentially one of the correct use of `biblatex`/`biber`, and has little to do with TikZ, so a list of starters with `biblatex` could be handy:

- [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/105447) (the link suggested by Alan Munn)
- [What to do to switch to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091)
- [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411)
- [`biblatex`'s documentation](http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

Comment: +1 And just to be clear to the OP, including the `.bib` file in your document with `{filecontents}` is *not* the way you would do it on a daily basis, but is included for the purposes of making a self-contained example. In normal practice you would have a separate `.bib` file which you maintain separately, ideally using an external tool like JabRef (multiplatform) or BibDesk (Mac).

Comment: Indeed, well remembered. I tried to keep it simple in the hope the link you supplied will get the OP started.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I complemented the answer in the spirit of your comment.