Drawing a hierarchical graph in ACM format without using Tikz package Latex
I am looking to draw a classification hierarchical diagram in Latex using the ACM template. I did one using the "Tikz" package already. However, I just realized that the ACM format forbids the "Tikz" package, which is usually used to create such diagrams. The "forest" package is also prohibited in ACM format.
Note: I cannot do the idea of making a Tikz-based graph and converting it into a figure later because I am citing papers inside the graph, and I want them to appear in the bibliography, and I do not want to use a table format.
An example of such a diagram is provided here:

any recommendations?

You could use \nocite to get the references into the bibliography of your paper and create the diagram separately. Depending on the citation style, you could import the numbers of the citations to your diagram.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

I'm  not sure what exactly you're looking for, but good old fashioned qtree can still make nice trees without resorting to TikZ.  If you show a forest version of the tree, it might not be too difficult to convert, unless you're doing a lot of fancy stuff.

@AlanMunn, looks like ACM excluded all Tikz derivates from the list of allowed packages. See here: https://authors.acm.org/proceedings/production-information/accepted-latex-packages.

@MS-SPO Yes, and qtree is not TikZ based, as I mentioned.

@AlanMunn ... not allowed, either. See said link

With the limitations by ACM in mind, you could use e.g. a generic reference style like [Altmann 96] rather than [1], [2}, [3]. This way you could work on your bibliography and a tree diagram in parallel, as those generics won't change any more.

@MS-SPO My apologies. I thought the prohibition was about TikZ and didn't look at the link.  So it looks like the only reasonable solution is to draw the tree with forest snd then include it as an image.

@AlanMunn, no problem, easy to overlook. Right, and combine with references to the bibliography. Not sure, if the separate images can be in .pdf, as then they can be included via graphicx AND updated with references separately. See here for this concept of class-splitting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701698/245790 . But even if not, other image formats can be created and updated that way, too. (Submission: all those pdf s AND the one Latex source)

Here is a sketch of the idea indicated in my comment. Create these documents:

main.tex, using the ACM class
biblio.bib or similar
tree.tex etc. for each drawing, using standalone, creating tree.pdf via compile

1. Bibliography
To show the relevant part I use the simplest form of a manually created thebibliography environment. In reality you won't do it this way, but use one of the bibilography related LaTeX tools.
The important point here is creating a generic entry, like [BEC03] via \bibitem[BEC03]{BECK03} ....
\begin{thebibliography}{2}
    \bibitem[BEC03]{BECK03} Beck, Kent (2003)
        \newblock \emph{Test-Driven Development}
        \newblock{Addison Wesley}       

    \bibitem[MUR12]{MUR12} Murphy, Kevin P. (2012)
        \newblock \emph{Machine Learing - A Probalistic Perspective}
        \newblock{The MIT Press}        

    \bibitem[TAN99]{TAN99} Tanenbaum, S., Andrew (1999)
        \newblock \emph{Structured Computer Organization}
        \newblock{Prentice Hall}
    
\end{thebibliography}

2. main.tex
Now you can cite some of the references in running text.
The tree is included in a way I understood ACM allows to. IF .pdf for a drawing is not allowed, you may want to convert it into a pixelformat, e.g. by using imagemagick.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}   % use ACM instead
\usepackage{graphicx}           % included there

\begin{document}
 This author tells all about computer architecture: \cite{TAN99}.
 
 \begin{figure}[b]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{tree} % loads tree.pdf
  \caption{Sources cited in this paper}
 \end{figure}
 
 \input{biblio.bib}
\end{document}


3. tree.tex
This code creates a simple (non-nice) tree using forest. Once you compiled it, forest and any other Tikz package are no longer noticeable to ACM.
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
 \begin{forest}grow=east
    [Topic
        [Design
            [BEC03][other]
        ]
        [MachineLearning
            [MUR12][\dots]  
        ]       
    ]
 \end{forest}
\end{document}


Using this generic citation allows you to define it once and then use it wherever you like, as it won't change.
If you have to use a numbered citation as in your drawing, it's a bit more effort to do.
However, if you need to introduce changes:

edit tree.tex first, and compile it (and do pixel conversion)
compile main.tex again
done

4. Using reference numbers with Tikz
A number of questions and solutions exist here, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380412/245790 .

Here's the missing "n" within my bibliography ... ;-)
